# Creating a dictionary using two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello everyone I have two lists:

```
a = ['x' , 'y']
b=[[1,2,], [-4,3,], [8,9,]]
```

I want to form a dictionary like this:

```
Dict={'x':[1,-4,8] , 'y':[2,3,9]}
```

Answer (score 2):

`zip` and `zip`:

```
a = ['x', 'y']
b = [[1, 2, ], [-4, 3, ], [8, 9, ]]

d = {x:list(y) for x, y in zip(a, zip(*b))}

print (d)

{'x': [1, -4, 8], 'y': [2, 3, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option with the benefit that it does not have to
create an intermediate value

```
a = ['x' , 'y']
b=[[1,2,], [-4,3,], [8,9,]]
di = dict(zip(a,(zip(*b)))) # => {'x': [1, -4, 8], 'y': [2, 3, 9]}
```

Answer (score 0):

if its really just to do what you are saying, the simplest and more readable way would be.

```py
a = ['x' , 'y']
b=[[1,2,], [-4,3,], [8,9,]]

dict = {a[0]:[], a[1]:[]}

for val in b:
    dict[a[0]].append(val[0])
    dict[a[1]].append(val[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to emphasize not to use python functions as variable names (list, dict,..) as this would overwrite the existing python function.

```py
a = ['x' , 'y']
b=[[1,2,], [-4,3,], [8,9,]]
c = [[i[0] for i in b], [i[1] for i in b]]
di = dict(zip(a,c)) # Note that if I had created a variable called dict before, this function won't work
di
{'x': [1, -4, 8], 'y': [2, 3, 9]}
```

Comment: Hi Ram thank you so much, but how do I go if  I have millions in a and b